# Hidden field value misinterpreted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following Rails 4.2 form is nested within the show action for `@promotion`.

```
<%= form_for(@attachment, url: add_image_attachments_path, multipart: true, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag('attachment[promotion_id]', @promotion.id) %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <%= f.text_field :caption %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
<% end %>
```

is generating as HTML

```
 <form class="new_attachment" id="new_attachment" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/attachments/add_image" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
   <input type="hidden" name="attachment[promotion_id]" id="attachment_promotion_id" value="1" />
```

which is as expected.

But the log is showing rails handling the hidden_field `promotion_id` with a different value, seemingly one of an authenticity_token

```
Started POST "/attachments/add_image" for ::1 at 2020-09-18 09:43:53 +0200
Processing by AttachmentsController#add_image as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "attachment"=>{"promotion_id"=>"uA5hl5TQ1Wc2SKjkwUDPr34y9CRkZbDTAZ4Gm4ACZhuR9kpwK+UTeobBXaUEulNfdr84XbJwe+Lujs3jei67XQ==", 
"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc1661cc008 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/hw/q8mvv1g54g9bj6y1j96vncrr0000gp/T/RackMultipart20200918-1932-jrlm13.png>, @original_filename="S_1.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment[image]\"; filename=\"S_1.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, 
"caption"=>"blurb"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
```

One can also note that it is being processed `as HTML` which contradicts the `data-remote` instruction.  Even flipping the form to `form_tag` syntax leads to the same behaviour.

If the form is submitted without  `remote: true` then the object is created with the proper parent referencing, but via HTML which is not the goal.

what could be causing rails to misread/mishandle the form?

Comment: `f.hidden_field :promotion_id, value: @promotion.id` does render; the object is created if no `remote: true` specified.

Comment: Are you using any JS base plugin for fileupload?

Comment: `carrierwave` gem is being used for fileupload and that does not involve javascript AFAIK. Niether does `fog` which it invokes.  But being a legacy app and with tons of JS strewn around... this is a useful hint. some conflict night be occurring...